# Renaming "Hey Siri"

Tags: siri

`Hey Siri` is too short: it keeps getting triggered when people talk around. Furthermore, I have several iOS devices: I would like to have a different voice command for each device. Is there any way to rename the voice command `Hey Siri` to turn on [Siri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri)?

Comment: just some info https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy

Comment: I wonder if Apple is planning on trying to tell who I am by my voice over time with "Hey Siri" or if they will recommend enabling it only on one watch / iPad / iPhone or have some other plan. For me, the utility of this is purely a parlor trick but I could see people not enabling this going forward due to confusion / hassle / fear of talking to the "wrong siri".

Comment: They already allow you to train your device to only activate "Hey Siri" with your voice with iOS 9. I guess that resolves the activation in public, at least. Apple could make devices communicate to know to which one are you talking to (e.g. if you are doing something on an Apple device, that'd be the only one to activate Siri; if you're not using any device it should activate the Watch or the iPhone if there's no Watch nearby or the iPad if there's no iPhone or Watch nearby).

Comment: Amazon is way ahead of Apple on this one with their Echo devices. There are several trigger words to chose from which makes the experience much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

There's no official way to rename the voice command to turn on Siri.

I've heard people discussing this after jailbreaking their devices, but I have no experience of that myself and wouldn't recommend it.